# Solving Volume with area only given

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Just some quick help I want to know if I did this correctly because I don't have an answer sheet.

Question:

If $2700cm^2$ of material is available to make a box with a square base and open top, find the dimensions that give the largest volume of the box.

What I did:
let h = height

A=$x^2$

A=$2700cm^2$

$x = 30root(3)$

V = $x^2h$

Derivative of V' = $2xh + x^2$

$0$ = $2xh + x^2$

$h = 15root(3)$

Max volume is $70148cm^3$

Is this correct? I have an exam in 40 minutes I'm stuck :(

Comment: The area of the square base $x^2$ is not the same as the surface area of the box and sides.  $x^2 + 4xh = 2700cm^2$.  So $h = (2700 - x^2)/4x$.  $V = x^2h = x^2(2700-x^2)/4x = x(2700 - x^2)/4$.  So max/min volumes are at $V' = (2700 - x^2)/4 + x(-x)/4 = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume of the box is given by: $$ V = x^2h$$
For the surface we have: $$x^2+4xh=2700$$
from the last equation, we get $h = \dfrac{2700-x^2}{4x}$ , replace in $V$ expression: $$V = 675x-\dfrac{1}{4}x^3$$

To get the max volume, set $\dfrac{dV}{dx} = 0$

solving that leads to : $x = 30 \,\text{ cm}$, $h = 15\,\text{ cm}$, $V = 13500\,\text{cm}^3$

Comment: So 2700 is the perimeter not the area?

Comment: 2700 is the surface available to construct the box

Comment: Ahhh I got it now thank you

Comment: the surface of the box is the surface of the base $x^2$ and 4 lateral surface each have $xh$

Answer (score 0):

Its wrong.

If $b$ is the side of the basis and $h$ the height, you have:

$$
b^2+4bh=2700 \quad \rightarrow \quad h=\frac{2700-b^2}{4b}
$$

And the volume is:
$V=b^2h$

Maximize this function.

Comment: How did you get 4bh?

Comment: Four lateral face of the box.

Comment: So b^2+4bh is equal to the area which is 2700? Or I am interpreting the question wrong?

Comment: Yes, correct, the total areal is the area of the basis $+$ the are of the four lateral faces( if the top is open as I think).